# Node JS - How to write stream big json data into json array file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have difficult to write a json data into json file using `stream` module.
I learn about this from several blog tutorial, one of them is this [page](https://www.sandersdenardi.com/readable-writable-transform-streams-node/)

Let say i am working with big json data on a json file. I think it is not possible to store all json object inside my memory. So i decided to do it using stream module.

Here the codes i have done:

writeStream.js

```
var Writable = require('stream').Writable,
util = require('util');

var WriteStream = function() {
    Writable.call(this, {
        objectMode: true
    });
};

util.inherits(WriteStream, Writable);

WriteStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log('write            : ' + JSON.stringify(chunk));
    callback();
};

module.exports = WriteStream;
```

readStream.js

```
var data = require('./test_data.json'),
Readable = require('stream').Readable,
util = require('util');

var ReadStream = function() {
    Readable.call(this, {
        objectMode: true
    });

    this.data = data;
    this.curIndex = 0;
};

util.inherits(ReadStream, Readable);

ReadStream.prototype._read = function() {
    if (this.curIndex === this.data.length) {
        return this.push(null);
    }

    var data = this.data[this.curIndex++];
    console.log('read             : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    this.push(data);
};

module.exports = ReadStream;
```

Called with this code:

```
var ReadStream = require('./readStream.js'),
WriteStream = require('./writeStream.js');

var rs = new ReadStream();
var ws = new WriteStream();
rs.pipe(ws);
```

Problem: I want to write it into different file, how is it possible?
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution to just write the data from your `ReadStream` into a different file, you can try [fs.createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options). It will return you a writeable stream which can be piped directly to your `ReadStream`.

You will have to make a minor change in your **readStream.js**. You are currently pushing an object thus making it an object stream while a write stream expects either String or Buffer unless started in the ObjectMode. So you can do one of the following:

- Start the write stream in the object mode. More info [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode).
- Push String or Buffer in your read stream as writable stream internally calls writable.write which expects either String or Buffer. More info [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback).

If we follow the second option as an example, then your **readStream.js** should look like this:

```
var data = require('./test_data.json'),
Readable = require('stream').Readable,
util = require('util');

var ReadStream = function() {
    Readable.call(this, {
        objectMode: true
    });

    this.data = data;
    this.curIndex = 0;
};

util.inherits(ReadStream, Readable);

ReadStream.prototype._read = function() {
    if (this.curIndex === this.data.length) {
        return this.push(null);
    }

    var data = this.data[this.curIndex++];
    console.log('read             : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    this.push(JSON.stringify(data));
};

module.exports = ReadStream;
```

You can call the above by using the following code

```
var ReadStream = require('./readStream.js');
const fs = require('fs');

var rs = new ReadStream();
const file = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/output/file');
rs.pipe(file);
```

This will write the data from test_data.json to the output file.

Also as a good practice and to reliably detect write errors, add a listener for the 'error' event. For the above code, you can add the following:

```
file.on('error',function(err){
  console.log("err:", err);
});
```

Hope this helps.